# jquery detach() inside custom click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a fairly complex situation (to me at least):

I have a click function that was used to show an overlay. Inside the click function, the element in question is determined dynamically:

```
$('a.overlay-show').click(function() {

var id = $(this).attr('id');
var el_id = '#project-details-overlay-' + id;
```

Now what I'd like to do is something like:

```
$(el_id).detach();
```

But I am seeing that this doesn't work because I am passing in an element not a selector. So how would one do this?

What I need to do is grab that element and re-attach it somewhere else. I have tried to just deal with the element's contents using `.html()` and so forth but because the content, at times contains javascript elements such as slideshows, this doesn't seem to work out too well...

Any suggestions?

Comment: `el_id` is  a selector - id selector

Comment: to place it somewhere else you can directly use append/prepend/after/before etc like `$(el_id).appendTo(newparent)`

Comment: That doesn't work. So something like this: `el_id.appendTo('#selected-project');` results in `Uncaught TypeError: Object #project-details-overlay-46 has no method 'appendTo'` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should work this way:

```
$('a.overlay-show').click(function() {

    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var el_id = $('#project-details-overlay-' + id);

    el_id.detach();

});
```

i'm not familiar with detach.. if you're trying to move it somewhere else:

```
<div id="somewhereElse"></div>
```

then you would write:

```
el_id.appendTo('#somewhereElse');
```

if you want to keep it where it is AND copy it somewhere else:

```
el_id.clone().appendTo('#somewhereElse');
```

lastly, if you're not using el_id anywhere else beyond this one line of code, you don't even need the extra variable... just condense the var statement and the append statement into one:

```
$('#project-details-overlay-' + id).appendTo('#somewhereElse');
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. Using `appendTo('#somediv');` results in `Uncaught TypeError: Object #project-details-overlay-46 has no method 'appendTo' ` ... ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @erikruina - `appendTo()` works much better. I ended up fixing it with

```
$('a.overlay-show').click(function() {

var id = $(this).attr('id');
var el_id = $('#project-details-overlay-' + id);
$(el_id).appendTo('#selected-project');

});
```

I suspect that the issue is that with `detach();` you also need to deal with all the child elements, whereas `appendTo()` just works.